# How to remove an item from Local Storage when clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage

I want to delete an item stored in Local Storage when it is clicked. But I don't know how to do that. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks a lot!!

[image]

[image]

the code right here:

```js
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('item')) || {
    products: [],
    quantity: 0,
    total: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      state.products.push(action.payload);
      state.quantity += 1;
      state.total += action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
      localStorage.setItem('item', JSON.stringify(state));
    },
    deleteItem: (state, action) => {
      state.products = state.products.filter((item) => {
        // 
      });
      state.quantity -= 1;
      state.total -= action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
    },
    reset: (state) => {
      return state;
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+remove+from+localstorage+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: [localStorage.removeItem](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_removeitem.asp). You can create a function and pass thet function the item name and then set that name in `localStorage.removeItem`